# Loading datatype in parquet file byte_array into AWS Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to load a parquet file into Redshift that has a column with **byte_array** datatype. I'm getting a Spectrum Scan error when trying to load this datatype. I've tried using varchar and varbyte but both don't seem to work.

Is there a datatype in Redshift that can be used to load the byte_array datatype?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same problem with the following Spectrum error:

`Spectrum Scan Error. File '.../part-00000-282929af.gz.parquet' has an incompatible Parquet schema for column '../part-00000-282929af.gz.parquet.date_set'. Column type: TIMESTAMP, Parquet schema: optional byte_array date_set [i:66 d:1 r:0]`

Changing the column type of `date_set` from `timestamp` to `TEXT` fixed this for me. It's weird since `TEXT` [is converted to `VARCHAR(256)` by Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_Character_types.html), but this worked for me